# If 30dB at 200 meters away, how much at origin?

Tags: acoustics, estimation, intensity

I want to organize an event in a public area, and I'm not sure how loud we can get. If the limit is 30 dB as measured at 200m away from the origin of the sound, what is the limit from its origin, in an open area?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics SE. Please, read the guidelines and the tour page. Homework-like questions are not welcomed here, unless they ask about a conceptual issue, and they must show some effort. Please, edit your question to fit these requirements, or else it will be probably put on hold by the community. Thank you.

Comment: How large is the origin of the sound?

Comment: @Dale Probably around 60-70 dB, if you're asking about size of the sound.

Comment: No, I mean the physical size of the sound source. i.e. in meters

Comment: The language "at the origin" sort of implies you are thinking of a point source of sound. In this case, the sound will be infinite at the origin. But this just an artifact of an unphysical assumption (a truly point-like source). This approximation is fine far away from the source, where the details of the source don't matter. But you want to know what the sound looks like near the source. Then you need to give more information. For example, is the source a speaker? What shape and size? Is it someone's vocal cords? To a first approximation, just knowing the size will give you some idea.

Answer (score 1):

Sound pressure level drops off with distance for a variety of reasons, but assuming the frequency of the sound is in the range of 0.1-10 kHz (like music or speech) the main one is just the sound spreading out, which causes the power per unit area to drop off with the square of the distance. What this means in terms of decibels is that every time you move to one-tenth the distance from the source, the loudness goes up by 20 dB.  So if it’s 30 dB at 200 m, it would be 70dB at 2 m.